# How to get specific string from dynamic string C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I am facing a problem extracting a specific string. I have following string (this may vary):

```
show inventory<br><br>Name: "My Device Name One", DESCR: "ASA 5506-X
SSD"<br>PID: ASA5506-SSD       , VID: N/A     , SN: MSA203301BV<br>WARD-99ST-FW01#Name:
"Chassis", DESCR: "ASA 5506-X with FirePOWER services, 8GE, AC, DES"<br>PID: ASA5506     
, VID: V06     , SN: JMX2042Y12V<br>Name: "Storage Device 1", DESCR: "ASA5506-X SSD"<br>
PID: ASA5506-SSD       , VID: N/A     , SN:MSA203301BV<br>WARD-99ST-FW01#
```

From this string I would like to parse "SN" where "Name"= Chassis. So from above string I need result="JMX2042Y12V". I would not like to use `</br>` tag for parsing as they will not come in some cases.

So far I have used this: (not working properly and it is based on `</br>` tag which I do not want to use.

```
private static List<string> ExtractFromBody(string body, string start, string end)
{
    List<string> matched = new List<string>();

    int indexStart = 0;
    int indexEnd = 0;

    bool exit = false;

    while (!exit)
    {
        indexStart = body.IndexOf(start);

        if (indexStart != -1)
        {
            indexEnd = indexStart + body.Substring(indexStart).IndexOf(end);

            matched.Add(body.Substring(indexStart + start.Length, indexEnd - indexStart - start.Length));

            body = body.Substring(indexEnd + end.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            exit = true;
        }
    }

    return matched;
}
```

And I am calling like this:

```
var result= ExtractFromBody(St, ", SN: ", "<br/>");

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.Write(r);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Wouldn't the regex `(SN: \w+)` do the trick?

Comment: I am open for anything regex/LinQ etc. Do you have any example... Also I need to check SN only for Name: "Chassis"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use a regular expression (in combination with your existing code that finds the starting index of the substring to search) for the SN

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var body = "show inventory<br><br>Name: \"My Device Name One\", DESCR: \"ASA 5506-XSSD\"<br>PID: ASA5506-SSD       , VID: N/A     , SN: MSA203301BV<br>WARD-99ST-FW01#Name:\"Chassis\", DESCR: \"ASA 5506-X with FirePOWER services, 8GE, AC, DES\"<br>PID: ASA5506 , VID: V06     , SN: JMX2042Y12V<br>Name: \"Storage Device 1\", DESCR: \"ASA5506-X SSD\"<br>PID: ASA5506-SSD       , VID: N/A     , SN:MSA203301BV<br>WARD-99ST-FW01#";

        var regex = new Regex("(SN: )(\\w+)");

        var indexStart = body.IndexOf("Chassis");

        var substringToParse = body.Substring(indexStart);

        var matchingResult = regex.Match(substringToParse);

        //SN: JMX2042Y12V
        var fullResult = matchingResult.Groups[0].Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"Full result: {fullResult}");

        //SN: (<- contains trailing space)
        var snGroup = matchingResult.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"SN group result (with trailing space): {snGroup}");

        //JMX2042Y12V
        var valueGroup = matchingResult.Groups[2].Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"Value group result: {valueGroup}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly, I have did little modification to ensure match exact word: 
int indexStart = body.IndexOf("Chassis");
Changed to this: 
            int indexStart = Regex.Match(body, @"\WChassis\W").Index;

Answer (score 0):

I used this `Name:\s?"Chassis"[\s\S]*?, SN:/s?(.{11})` regular expression to find all the matches and then retrieved group 1 from every match

I also assumed that every SN id will have exactly 11 characters, as we need to know when the SN stops *EDIT:* you can use `(\w+)` instead of `(.{11})`

Here you go:

```
        string someHtml = "show inventory<br><br>Name: \"My Device Name One\", DESCR: \"ASA 5506 - XSSD\"<br>PID: ASA5506-SSD       , VID: N/A     , SN: MSA203301BV<br>WARD-99ST-FW01#Name:\"Chassis\", DESCR: \"ASA 5506-X with FirePOWER services, 8GE, AC, DES\" < br > PID: ASA5506, VID: V06     , SN: JMX2042Y12V<br> Name: \"Chassis\", DESCR: \"ASA5506-X SSD \" < br > PID: ASA5506 - SSD       , VID: N / A     , SN: MSA203301BV<br> WARD-99ST - FW01#";


        Regex FindHwndWrapper = new Regex("Name:\\s?\"Chassis\"[\\s\\S]*?, SN:\\s?(.{11})");

        MatchCollection matches = FindHwndWrapper.Matches(someHtml);

        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
```